# Get hAxis height of a column chart (google chart)

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I cannot find a way to get the dimensions nor the position of the hAxis of my Column chart.

I've tried those but none work (all return `null`).

```
cli.getBoundingBox('hAxis#0#gridline');
cli.getBoundingBox('hAxis#gridline');
cli.getBoundingBox('hAxis#0');
cli.getBoundingBox('hAxis');
```

Comment: can you post your full code?

Answer (score 0):

Posting my code would be complicated, it's a Angular 5 app, so there is components and services everywhere. But I figured out I can get the height of what I want by doing so

```
function getHeight(cli) {
  var chartBox = cli.getBoundingBox('chart');
  var areaBox = cli.getBoundingBox('chartarea');

  return chartBox.height - areaBox.height;
}
```